# MongoDB inserts pausing inconsistently (or getting swapped out)

Tags: performance, mongodb, memory-management, insert

There is a 9 million records file being inserted using a perl script. No bulk inserts/mongoimport are being used because of the need to do some processing on each record before insertion.

The program takes 40 minutes to complete, but for some reason, it keeps pausing (getting swapped out?) every now and then and hence the running time doubles,triples and sometimes just gets unbearably slow. I have 7 GB RAM and when I check using free -m it says I have around 5 GB of free RAM when the program is running. I do not have any resource-consuming processes running. What is the reason for this slowness? Would it be a mongo issue or a OS issue? How do I go about solving the issue? Thank you.

Comment: By default Mongo syncs the writes with the disc every minute, so while the inserts will be fast, on each minute it will have to flush them on disk, leading to increased I/O. This may cause your pauses.

Comment: Oh is there any way to address this issue? Maybe instruct Mongo to flush after every hour or something? Thanks for the info.

Comment: Set the [syncdelay](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#syncdelay) setting

Comment: I just saw the MongoDocs for how to do that. I have set it to 0 and the pausing seems to have reduced even though not completely. Would this be better than setting it to a higher number? Also if you could post these comments as an answer I would accept it and it would be useful for future readers. Thank you for that information.

Comment: If you set to 0, the data won't be written to the disk at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Mongo syncs the writes with the disc every minute, so while the inserts will be fast, on each minute it will have to flush them on disk, leading to increased I/O. This causes a slow-down about every minute.

You can change the [default setting](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#syncdelay) to higher, but you will lose your data in case of power outage, or you can fsync every second - in this case the entire operation will be much slower, but with
sustained speed.

Comment: Oh.. This might be something really obvious to you, but can I sync it all at once later in the day. That way Once the inserts are done and I do the necessary querying I can then run the fsync as a background thing and not worry about the speed?